# Mouse controlling software

Tags: windows, automation, mouse

Every day I export a report from an online database, and I'm trying to learn whether this could be automated.

The process involves moving the mouse 5 times and clicking, and this is why I'm asking about software that could control my mouse in a pre-programmed way, but for the automation to work it would have to understand when the webpages involved have finished loading.

Any suggeestions or advice in this matter is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Well, what's your mouse connected to? Are solutions for AmigaOS acceptable? ;) Honestly: while the *topic* seems clear, you need at least to specify what OS this should be running on. It might also be helpful to indicate if that "clicking" is on a web page (if so: what browsers can be used?) or a native application. Those details will help us to give you better tailored answers.

Comment: @Izzy Thank you for the welcome :). I apologise for omitting the Windows version from the tags, while posting this from my phone the tag field suggested "windows-xp", but once selected it informed me that I was trying to create a new tag, and in my hurry I omitted to at least enter "Windows". The process would ideally involve clicking within a virtual machine, but I have a hunch this would additionally complicate things. I'm looking for a solution that would at least work with Internet Explorer 7.

Comment: @AnastasiosVentouris I found that question but as far as I could tell the answers are not what I'm looking for, since I'm looking for software that could somehow identify a webpage's loading status. Do you suggest otherwise?

Comment: For something like this, you will need programming language. For example in python, you can use selenium. I am not aware of something else. Sorry

Comment: @Dirk101 – check the answer Anastasios Ventouris linked few comments ago. Click the mouse using AutoHotKey `Click` command. Get the color of pixel on screen using `PixelGetColor` or text of desired control using `ControlGetText` command. This way you can determine whether page loading has finished.

Comment: @miroxlav Thanks for the help, I'm looking into it right now. If your comment is the answer I was looking for, there's no answer for me to choose. Is that ok according to site rules?

Comment: @Dirk101 – you can encourage helpful commenter to write an answer based on the comment, this is what I also usually do in these cases :)  I'll prepare an answer for you.

Comment: @Dirk101 Sorry I couldn't answer your comment before, they seem to have trouble in the SE data center (outages). I've added the relevant tags for you. Looks like your answer is approaching :)

Comment: So, you mean that some program to automatize browser actions? Or just any kind of mouse action?

Comment: @Izzy Thanks again, I realize I should have thought to edit my own tags now that you've done it for me

Comment: @Braiam Ideally it would be mouse actions. The actions to be done are within a virtual machine GUI, and I don't have access to install software within the virtual machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many times, [AutoHotKey](http://autohotkey.com) can automate these actions.

In Autohotkey macro you can for example:

- send keystrokes using Send` command
- click the mouse using AutoHotKey `Click` command
- get the color of pixel on screen using `PixelGetColor`
- get text of desired control using `ControlGetText` command.
- and many more.

This way you can determine whether page loading has finished.

If you cannot install anything to the machine, you can still go with [portable AutoHotKey package.](http://ahkscript.org/download/)

**EDIT:** do not forget to run AutoHotKey **as administrator.**

Comment: Making it portable is an ideal solution, I'll look into the compiler.

Comment: @Dirk101 – You have two options: (1) deploy portable AHK and you can still fine-tune your macros inside it (2) compile your macro with AHK on another machine and deploy only resulting EXE file. I'd prefer (2) only if macro sources should be hidden from someone's view, otherwise I'd view (1) as more practical.